# Google OAuth API called from Javascript getting HTTP cancelled

Tags: javascript, jquery, oauth-2.0

I am trying to make HTTPS call to google OAuth API from Jquery/Javascript:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=<STATE>&redirect_uri=<HTTPS  REDIRECT URI>&response_type=token&client_id=<CLIENT_ID>
```

It is getting HTTP cancelled instead of routing to google login page.

Debugging using chrome://net-internals shows that the browser is receiving a "302 Moved Temporarily" response from Google API with the following location header:

```
location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&passive=1209600...
```

But the browser is not able to follow the redirection and following errors are seen in net-internals:

```
t=1378152699506 [st=57]     -HTTP_TRANSACTION_READ_HEADERS
t=1378152699506 [st=57]      HTTP_CACHE_WRITE_INFO  [dt=0]
t=1378152699506 [st=57]     +URL_REQUEST_BLOCKED_ON_DELEGATE  [dt=1]
t=1378152699506 [st=57]        SPDY_STREAM_UPDATE_RECV_WINDOW
                               --> delta = -847
                               --> stream_id = 11
                               --> window_size = 10484913
t=1378152699507 [st=58]        CANCELLED
t=1378152699507 [st=58]   -URL_REQUEST_START_JOB
                           --> net_error = -3 (ERR_ABORTED)
```

t=1378152699508 [st=59] -REQUEST_ALIVE

Can anyone help on why chrome is not able to follow the redirection ? What does URL_REQUEST_BLOCKED_ON_DELEGATE mean ?

Comment: I resolved this problem by changing the design by using window.open() instead of making ajax call to google oauth API. Since my ultimate goal is to ask the users to login into google, this change in design worked. I am not sure about the root cause of getting "HTTP request cancelled" in the original problem. Anyway, I think the google oauth API to get user's consent is meant to be used with window.open() or other ways to open a new window or iframe to prompt the user, and NOT simple ajax fire and forget call.

Comment: You are correct. Same Origin Policy will stop you calling those URLs from your app, and they are not meant to be called that way.

Comment: Just wanted to make one thing clear - I had indeed registered my app in google oauth api console by providing Javascript origin and redirect uri. So maybe its working with respect to same origin policy and the problem was just with the way I was invoking the call.